# Começar exibição da div pelo final do Scroll

Tags: jquery, css

E ae pessoal, blz? Pessoal, parece até uma dúvida besta a priore, mas procurei e não encontrei algo relacionado, tenho uma div com listas dentro

```
etc...
li.intem3
li.intem2
li.intem1
```

Quando eu carrego a página, ele inicia a exibição pelo TOP da Div, e eu queria que ele iniciasse a exibição pelo BOTTOM, pronto, o chat do facebook, ele inicia a exibição das mensagens pelo final, aí a pessoa vai subindo o scroll pra ver as mais antigas, quero dessa forma vllw pessoal... E perdão pelas Tag's, Nn sei em qual isso se encaixa.

Comment: Cara nessa resposta tem alguns exemplos, inclusive acabei de colocar lá um que é feito apenas com CSS caso te interesse. Se resolver vc pode marcar como duplicada se for o caso... Se não for o que vc precisa é só dar mais detalhes.

Comment: Veja esse link aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div ou esse:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: O seu com Css era oq eu queria, mas da forma que colocou, Nn consegui encaixar em meu código

Comment: Cara te dei uma nova opção apenas com CSS diferente da da outra resposta. As vezes agora te atende...

Answer (score 0):

Vou colocar aqui um exemplo usando `Jquery` e `animação`, que mostra o conteúdo "rolando" como se alguém estivesse mesmo rodando o scroll do mouse.

A mágica fica por parte do jquery, e a chamada é :

```
$('#divQueQueroScrollar').stop().animate({
  scrollTop: $('#divQueQueroScrollar')[0].scrollHeight
}, 1500);
```

O `1500` é a velocidade da animação, sendo em `milissegundos`, ou seja, um segundo e meio.

Segue o snippet executável para ver como fica:

```js
$('#divQueQueroScrollar').stop().animate({
  scrollTop: $('#divQueQueroScrollar')[0].scrollHeight
}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divQueQueroScrollar" style="border: solid 1px #000; width: 100px; text-align: center; overflow: scroll; height: 100px;  ">
1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>10<br/>11<br/>12<br/>13<br/>14<br/>15<br/>16<br/>17<br/>18<br/>19<br/>20<br/>21<br/>22<br/>23<br/>24<br/>25<br/>26<br/>27<br/>28<br/>29<br/>30<br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como vc falou que as outras resposta não te atenderam vou te dar uma outra opção apenas com CSS usando flexbox.

A técnica consiste em inverter a direção do conteúdo da div usando `flex-direction: column-reverse` então o conteúdo sempre começa embaixo e vai sendo empurrado pra cima.

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor:

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div> /* essa div na verdade começa de baixo pra cima */
    <div class="inner">Primeira mensagem</div>
  <div class="inner">oi</div>
  <div class="inner">oi</div>
  <div class="inner">oi</div>
  <div class="inner">oi</div>
  <div class="inner">oi</div>
  <div class="inner">oi</div>
  <div class="inner">oi</div>
  <div class="inner">oi</div>
  <div class="inner">oi</div>
  <div class="inner">oi</div>
  <div class="inner">Última menssagem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Essa solução pode não ser totalmente *crossbrowser*, seria interessante vc testar no Safari, no IE não funciona...